# Fubini-Study norm of homogeneus polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let us consider the complex projective line $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$, by direct exam of the degrees we have the isomorphism: $$ T \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C}) \simeq \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})}(2).$$

Let  $X_0$ and $X_1$ be the homogeneus coordinates, and define affine local coordinates $\zeta_0 =\frac{X_0}{X_1}$ on $U_0=\{[X_0:X_1]\in\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})\,|\,X_1\neq 0\}$ and $\zeta_1:= \zeta_0^{-1}$ on $U_1$. Then complex homogeneus polynomials in $X_0,X_1$ of degree $2$, i.e. global sections of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})}(2)$, are identified with global sections of the holomorphic tangent bundle.

We introduce the [Fubini-Study metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%E2%80%93Study_metric) on $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$, which is a Hermitian form on the holomorphic tangent bundle and therefore on $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})}$. This allows us to define a Fubini-Study-$L^2$-norm on homogeneus polynomials by 
$$\|p(X_0,X_1)\|_{L^2,FS}^2 := \int_{\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})} \|p(X_0,X_1)\|_{FS}^2(z)\; \omega_{FS}(z).$$

**Question** How can I practically compute this norms?

It seems to me that first I have to explicit the isomorphism with the tangent bundle, tentatively:
\begin{align}
X_0^2 & \mapsto & \zeta_0^2 \partial_{\zeta_0} &= -\partial_{\zeta_1},\\
X_0X_1 & \mapsto & \zeta_0 \partial_{\zeta_0} &= -\zeta_1 \partial_{\zeta_1},\\
X_1^2 & \mapsto & \partial_{\zeta_0} &= - \zeta_1^2 \partial_{\zeta_1}.
\end{align}

Then I can plug-in the explicit form of the Fubini-Study inner product and associated volume form:
$$h_{FS}(\partial_{\zeta_i},\overline\partial_{\zeta_i}) = \frac{1}{\left(1+|\zeta_i|^2\right)^2}, \qquad \omega_{FS} (\zeta_i) = \frac{i}{2} \frac{1}{\left(1+|\zeta_i|^2\right)^2} d\zeta_i \wedge d\bar \zeta_i,\qquad \text{ on } U_i.$$

But this leads to not-easily-solvable rational integrals, and, having in mind the idea to generalize it to higer degree homogeneus polynomials, it doesn't seem promising. Is what I wrote correct? Is there a more direct and/or intrinsic way to compute these norms?

Thank you!

Comment: Remember that these integrals don't look so scary when you convert to polar coordinates in $\Bbb C$. That is, after all, how one evaluates $\displaystyle\int_{\Bbb P^1}\omega_{FS}$ in the first place.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks! Evaluating $\int_{\mathbb{P^1}} \omega_{FS}$ is exactly what made me suspicious in the first place. By breaking the integral in the two domains $\{|\zeta_0|<1\}$ and $\{|\zeta_1|<1\}$ and switching to polar coordinates I reduce it to $2\cdot \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \frac{r}{(1+r^2)^2} dr \wedge d\theta$, which integrates to $2\pi \left[ \frac{r}{1+r^2} +\arctan(r)\right]_0^1 = \pi + \pi^2/4$. But this is not what I expected! On one hand I could ask you to check my computation, but on the other one it would be easier just to get a reference to somewehere where it's done!

Comment: No, that's not right. You're missing some pullback correction. Just integrate over of all of $\Bbb C$ (missing just the one point at infinity).